# deep injection - spring

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

What is the best way (or options) for accessing spring components at layers deep within the application that aren't managed by spring?

For example, say I have some @Controllers. Via some layers of abstraction via POJOs that aren't managed by spring, those @Controllers might end up using a POJO that needs a @Service injected into it.

One option would be to make all the layers in to spring components, but that seems like I'm hacking my design to force spring to help me. I have some complex things going on that won't be nearly as clean if I have to @Autowire everything. Another option might be to manually inject the component in the low level class, but I'm not really sure if this is possible or the right solution.

Comment: My intuition is that if things are "layers away" from each other, then they should not depend on each other.

Comment: @rolve - I'm not sure I understand the comment but I think my reply is that "they don't". The LowLevelHelper POJO needs to use a \@Service class to access the DB. It does not depend on any of the layers above it.

Comment: @rolve - I think I realize the confusion - the spring components that the LowLevelHelper POJO needs to use are not the same components that are at the top of the "layers". I'll clear this up in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of answering the original question, I’ll say that you can make your low-level non-spring class implement ApplicationContextAware to get access to the ApplicationContext, and use the ApplicationContext to access any spring bean you want. (google search on “spring application context aware” to find [sample code](http://blog.jdevelop.eu/2008/07/06/access-the-spring-applicationcontext-from-everywhere-in-your-application/))

However, in the spirit of addressing the big picture here, there are a couple of problems with this question from the start. For one, It sounds like you have high-level components that you want to inject into low-level components - and usually you want your design to be the other way around. Additionally, as has been pointed out, things that are “layers away” from each other should probably not depend on each other. Improving the design with these points in mind will help you in this case.

I would not shy away from making all the layers into spring components to take full advantage of the framework you’re already using. If you want to use a DI framework, it’s generally helpful to use it to construct your entire application. And I would argue that a clean design, using @Inject (a Java EE standard) throughout, and using DI framework wiring with scope control is actually cleaner than having to “new” everything.

Comment: Maybe I do want to use the DI framework everywhere. I see your point about mixing/matching how things are created, but all of the application will never need to be spring components, so it seems wrong to force it that way. The framework should help me, not force me to cater to it.

I tried to clarify the original post - the low level class does not depend on the spring components using it; it depends on other spring components that the high level Controllers don't know about.

Comment: I've decided to go w/ the method from the sample code you shared. There is just too much other stuff going on that would end up being very unnatural if I try to force it in to a fully spring managed design. Thanks!